# Replace text in html usin ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to replace 'I really' with content of `e.ireally`. How can I do that?

```
window.jsonpCallback = function (e) {
    ($("#htmlpage").html(<h1 class="cter" id ="test">I really<span> <b>LOVE</b></span></h1>)
}
```

Comment: Firstly fix the syntax errors in your code due to missing quotes around the string, then simply just concatenate the values

Comment: can i do ..<h1 class="cter" id ="test">I really<span> <b>LOVE</b></span></h1>),$('#test').text(e.ireally);

Comment: where should i place $('#test').text(e.ireally);

Comment: I added an answer to show you

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to fix the syntax errors in your code due to the missing quotes around the string, then you can simply just concatenate the values. Also note that using a parameter named `e` for data passed to the function is not standard practice. `e` normally refers to an event, not an object. Finally, you don't need to wrap your code in parentheses. Try this:

```
window.jsonpCallback = function(data) {
    $("#htmlpage").html('<h1 class="cter" id="test">' + data.ireally + ' <span><b>LOVE</b></span></h1>')
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but i get Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list the html is breaking at the  ' + data.ireally +  ' at the '

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce that. The code above works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/3fe7g3rL/. Could you update your question to include more of your code - seeing the data returned from the AJAX call would help.

Comment: The error sounds like you have mismatched quotes around the string value (like this: https://jsfiddle.net/3fe7g3rL/1/). Make sure you've copied the code above entirely. I'd also strongly suggest you use a code editor with syntax highlighting so mistakes like that are almost impossible to make.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you..

```
   window.jsonpCallback = function(data) {
        $("#htmlpage").html("<h1 class='cter' id='test'>" + data.ireally + " <span><b>LOVE</b></span></h1>");
    }
```

Comment: `I want to replace 'I really' with content of e.ireally. How can I do that?`

Comment: Cool, that got it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130584/discussion-between-hikmat-sijapati-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: Just FYI, I'm not the OP

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you create a variable content h1 first, like that

```
var str = "<h1 class='cter' id ='test'>I really<span> <b>LOVE</b></span></h1>"
```

After that, find 'I really' in str and replace it with 'e.ireally'

```
window.jsonpCallback = function (e) {
  var str = str.replace("I really", e.ireally);
  $("#htmlpage").html(str);
}
```